# Pre-fill a text message with web page title

Tags: html, text, sms

I work in real estate and want the option to text to find out more. But as there are multiple web pages for different properties, I want the Page Title to pre-fill into the text so I know which property they are enquiring about. Is this possible? I've looked everywhere and not finding much luck. I know how to pre-fill text; just not pre-fill using site data.

Example of text:
"Tell me more about 23 Smith Street"
"Tell me more about

Comment: please describe what you've tried so far and share some code

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm not sure the context, but `document.title` should get you the page title.